# Pitch and Roll with acceleration greater than +/- 1g

Tags: python, math, accelerometer, euler-angles

I'm looking to compute the pitch and roll of a device fitted with a three axis accelerometer when it is not at rest or moving at a constant velocity. Most applications I've seen so far are for stationary tilt sensing... genuinely stuck on this one! Aiming to use it for a python program I'm working on.

For a stationary case I have the following:

```
Roll = np.arctan2(a_y, a_z) * 180/np.pi
Pitch = np.arctan2(a_x, np.sign(a_z)*np.sqrt(np.power(a_y,2) + np.power(a_z,2)))*180/np.pi
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @wnnmaw : "I'm looking to compute the pitch and roll of a device fitted with a three axis accelerometer when it is not at rest or moving at a constant velocity" and "For a stationary case I have the following..." ... I have equations for a device at rest that is being rotated about various axes based on accelerometer readings... but what happens when you have the device accelerating in some direction and you want to find its orientation?

Comment: Are yaw and acceleration known?

Comment: you can't. unless you know the acceleration and can deduce it from your measurements, there is no way to differentiate the acceleration from gravity and the acceleration from someone pushing it.

Comment: Stack Overflow focuses on coding based questions. It sounds like you're struggling with how to model the physics involved, which is not on topic for this site.  When you get to implementing the actual code for your model and you find a problem you can't overcome, post it here and we can help you

Comment: Maybe try this question on [the physics Stack Exchange site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @njzk2 ah damn... I thought I could find a work around for finding linear acceleration if I minimised the yaw (and thus set to 0) and found angles for pitch and roll. Plan was to multiple this rotation matrix by g and then subtract from the measured acceleration.

Comment: one information you have, though, is that gravity should not be representing more that `|g|`, therefore if you have hypothesis on some of your variables (such as `yaw == 0`), and if your know the linear acceleration direction, then maybe you can restrict your model enough to find pitch and roll (although I don't see how yaw is involved in your model)

Comment: Before you can solve this task, you need to disprove Einstein's theory of general relativity, which states that gravity and acceleration are the same thing. There is no way to know which way is down if you don't assume the device is not being accelerated.

Comment: @Hyperboreus yaw = 0, acceleration unknown.

Comment: @wnnmaw just posted it there.

Comment: @njzk2 One of the reasons I see people saying that linear acceleration can't be found with a three axis accelerometer is due to the fact that it can't distinguish what's happening with rotation around the axis gravity acts in, yaw. Due to the nature of the gestures being investigated the yaw is near 0 and above is the resultant rotation matrix for such a case.

Comment: without heavy filtering and a robust (global gravity / device position / device orientation) estimation is this task unsolvable. And even if you add estimations then the accuracy goes to hell cumulative with time ... very quickly. also you would need the actual G-sensor positions respect to device center of gravity. Also there is problem that many sensors are just to +/-2G which is not enough sometimes ...